# Retrieving list items from an array in Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, list

I have a collection of li:

```
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
<li>item4</li>
```

I need to push this into an array

```
var arrayItem ={};
```

After doing some filtering, I need to display it in the body. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can store the text of all li element in array:

```
var arrayItem = $('li').map(function(){
  return $(this).text()
}).get();
```

And for rendering above array into li collection:

```
$.each( arrayItem , function( index, value ){
   $('ul').append("<li>"+value+"</li>");
});
```

Comment: Thank you Milind for the comment. Is there a way I could do it using 'push'?

Comment: yes you can. but that is lengthy way of doing it. do you still want that??

Comment: I would appreciate if you could help me with the 'push' method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('li').each(function(){  arrayItem.push($(this).text()) })`

Comment: Thank you Milind. How do I retrieve the text and display it ?